# Cufon Refresh on JQuery In Woocommerce

Tags: jquery, ajax, refresh, cufon, woocommerce

I have a cufon H2 tag in the shipping method selection on my woocommerce site. The "CART TOTALS" text, and the "TOTAL" at the bottom are cufon formatted.

The page loads fine of course with the cufon font. However when the shipping method is changed, function woocommerce_ajax_update_shipping_method() is called in woocommerce-ajax.php.

Here is the code:

```
function woocommerce_ajax_update_shipping_method() {
        global $woocommerce;

        check_ajax_referer( 'update-shipping-method', 'security' );

        if ( ! defined('WOOCOMMERCE_CART') ) define( 'WOOCOMMERCE_CART', true );

        if ( isset( $_POST['shipping_method'] ) ) $_SESSION['_chosen_shipping_method'] =     $_POST['shipping_method'];

    $woocommerce->cart->calculate_totals();

    woocommerce_cart_totals();

    die();
}
```

I have tried to get cufon to refresh within that code block.

```
Cufon.refresh();
```

does not work, neither do any of the examples I could find in other answers here. There must be something quite simple I am missing.

Can someone shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 0):

Try calling Cufon.refresh() after the ajax has completed.